# Smali - Can't call instance constructor

Tags: java, android, smali

I am editing a .smali file and I need to just create an instance of a class, and then call it's constructor with a few parameters, however the resulting bytecode calls "this(…)" instead, even though I'm specifying the context to be used.

```
const-string v3, "string"

new-instance v2, Lcom/a/b/c/ClassName;

invoke-direct {v2, p0, v3}, Lcom/a/b/c/ClassName;-><init>([BLjava/lang/String;)V
```

Which resulted in:

```
ClassName className = new ClassName();
this(arrayOfByte, "string");
```

Trying to find any other simple examples on how to call constructors, I found the following code from [this PDF](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/%7Ejoel.reardon/mobile/smali-cheat.pdf):

```
new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V
```

However, the decompiled bytecode returned:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
this();
```

What am I doing wrong? It's as simple of an example as possible, however it still breaks, even without arguments.

Comment: It looks to me like whatever decompiler you're using isn't decompiling it properly, tbh. A new-instance followed by an invoke-direct on the constructor is the correct way to instantiate a new object.

Comment: @JesusFreke I thought of that, however the other smali files, and even the other calls in the same exact file are decompiled as expected, it only appears to be a problem in the edited function, and trying to recompile like this results in the app hanging. Another odd behavior is function returns being stored as "String str2 = a.b(); String str1 = str2;", with this redundant variable. Could my variable naming scheme cause both of these? This is my first time at the rodeo and I'm still a bit unsure of the possible ripple effects.